# how to add new line to email contents?

Tags: android, email

I want to Place content like

1. Name
2. Pass
3. Email

to the email content. how to do this...?

I tried this but not working.

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "First Name : "         + fname.getText().toString());
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Last Name : "                  + lname.getText().toString());
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email : "                  + email.getText().toString());
```

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use a `StringBuilder` to create all your content and then add it to your intent ?

```
StringBuilder sb;

sb.append("First Name : ");
sb.append(fname.getText().toString());
sb.append('\n');
sb.append("Last Name : ");
sb.append(lname.getText().toString());
sb.append('\n');
sb.append("Email : ");
sb.append(email.getText().toString());

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sb);
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a single String containing everything including "\n" for every line-break.

```
StringBuilder emailBody = new StringBuilder("First Name : ");
emailBody.append(fname.getText()).append("\n");
emailBody.append("Last Name : ").append(lname.getText()).append("\n");
emailBody.append("Email : ").append(email.getText());
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , emailBody.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do like this

```
String output = "FirstName :\nLastName :\nEmail ";
```

and add the string to the email content:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, output);
```