# How to insert new line in mail body

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add new line to email contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386904/how-to-add-new-line-to-email-contents)

I want to send an email in the following format:

```
name: name
email: email
address: address
```

But when I send the mail, it is received as follows:

```
NameEmailAddress
```

How can I insert a new line between these?

my code is

```
    private void sendEMail(String message) {
    AppSheredPref pref = new AppSheredPref(this);
    String supplierEmailId = pref.getSupplierEmailId();
    String loggedIn = pref.getLoggedInEmailId();

    //String to = supplierEmailId;

    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{loggedIn,supplierEmailId});

    //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
    //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});

    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App Finance");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    //need this to prompts email client only
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

}
```

Comment: i tried but its not working.it then comes like name/n address/n.....

Comment: @Avinash Use `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386904/how-to-add-new-line-to-email-contents check this.. implement.. and then delete your own question as its a duplicate of many others

Comment: @Avinash Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it might help you.

```
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App Finance");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Name:. XYZ \n\nemail:xyz@gmail.com\n\nAddress:XYZ");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to solve this issue.

1) Use StringBuilder for that

```
StringBuilder sb;

sb.append("Name : ");
sb.append('\n');
sb.append("Email : ");
sb.append('\n');
sb.append("Address : ");

mInEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sb);
```

2) Use Html.fromHtml(StringValue) for that

```
String str = "Name:- <br></br> Email:- <br></br> Address:- <br></br>";
mInEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(str));
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: You should probably [credit this answer to where you got it from](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8386991/1438733) since, y'know, that's what you're supposed to do. ;)

Comment: @Eric No I am using this code in my application also.

Comment: @downvoter Please specify the reason for downvote so i can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your body content is **HTML**, then you need to use **< /br>**

And if your body content is simple **TEXT** then you need to use simply **\n**

Hope it will help you.