# Sms breaking lines in Android

Tags: android, sms, send

I want to use this command:

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("123456789", null, "Hello World", null, null);
```

And I was wondering if I could send a sms with a line break. To make myself clear. I wonder if I can do this:

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("123456789", null, "Hello \nWorld", null, null);
```

Or, is it another way of doing it???

Comment: yes you can send this way.

Comment: I tried it and didn't work.

Comment: "Hello \nWorld" change as "Hello \n World" and try

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a StringBuilder to create all your content and then add it to your intent ?

[how to add new line to email contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386904/how-to-add-new-line-to-email-contents)

Comment: because `SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage` doen't recognice StringBuilder.

Comment: Use the `StringBuilder.toString()` function to convert it to a string